# Counting non-unique items in an Elasticsearch aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use an Elasticsearch aggregation to return all non-unique counts for each term within a bucket.

Given a mapping:-

```js
{
  "properties": {
    "addresses": {
      "properties": {
        "meta": {
          "properties": {
            "types": {
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a document:-

```js
{
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "types": [
          {
            "type": "Home"
          },
          {
            "type": "Home"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Fax"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The following `terms` aggregation:-

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": 3
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "addresses.meta.types.type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives this result:-

```js
  "aggregations" : {
    "types" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Business",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Fax",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Home",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

As you can see the terms are unique and I'm really after a total count of each e.g. Home: 2, Business: 3 and Fax: 1.

Is this possible?

I had a look at `value_count` but as it's not a bucket aggregation it seems a little less convenient to use. Alternatively possible a script might do it but I'm not too sure on the syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt if that is possible using [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type in Elasticsearch. The reason is that most of the metrics aggregations is w.r.t *the count of documents for particular occurrence of word* and not *counts of occurrence of words in documents*.

You may have to change the type of your field `type` to [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) so that ES would end up saving each `type` inside `types` as separate document.

I've provided sample mapping, document(no change in representation), aggregation query and response below.

### Sample Mapping:

```
PUT nested_test
{ 
   "mappings":{ 
      "properties":{ 
         "id":{ 
            "type":"integer"
         },
         "first_name":{ 
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{ 
               "keyword":{ 
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         },
         "second_name":{ 
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{ 
               "keyword":{ 
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         },
         "addresses":{ 
            "properties":{ 
               "meta":{ 
                  "properties":{ 
                     "types":{ 
                        "type":"nested",                <----- Note this
                        "properties":{ 
                           "type":{ 
                              "type":"keyword"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Document (No change)

```
POST nested_test/_doc/1
{
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "types": [
          {
            "type": "Home"
          },
          {
            "type": "Home"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Business"
          },
          {
            "type": "Fax"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that every type above is now considered *as a separate document* linked to the main document.

### Aggregation Query:

All that would be required is to make use of [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) + [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

```
POST nested_test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myterms": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "addresses.meta.types"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "myterms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "addresses.meta.types.type",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 2                       <----- Note this to filter only values with non unique counts
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in the above query I've made use of `min_doc_count` in order to restrict the results as per what you are looking for.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "myterms" : {
      "doc_count" : 6,
      "myterms" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Business",
            "doc_count" : 3
          },
          {
            "key" : "Home",
            "doc_count" : 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!